# What is the fastest way from Zurich to Milan

Tags: public-transport, car-rentals, zurich, milan

I have an event in Milan

My flight transit in Zurich before MXP in Milan

I am thinking this can be a great opportunity to enjoy the Swiss views and drive to Milan from Zurich

I checked for car rental it was around $650 for one day (pick up from Zurich airport, drop off MXP)

is there any other way to do that? public transport or any other way?

Comment: There's a rather quick train

Comment: How much time do you have? Do you actually need to get to MXP or rather to Milano (or elsewhere)?

Comment: i have around 5 hours

Answer (score 4):

You can take the EC (EuroCity) train direct from Zurich to Milan for a travel time of 3h17min (I don't know if there is that much scenery though)

Or you can take a bus like FlixBus to do that journey on the road for a ~4h journey time

Comment: train sounds great, do you know its website?

Comment: @asmgx SBB.ch is the website of the Swiss Federal Railways. Note that the fastest trains take the 57 km Gotthard base tunnel (longuest railway tunnel in the world), so that may cut out quite a bit of the scenery, if you have (a lot) more time there are lots of alternate routes, though I couldn’t say which one would be the most spectacular.

Comment: Bernina is the most spectacular because it doesn't use tunnels -- but if you take that route your time might reach ten hours.